# Observer for a single model in an Ember.ArrayController's array model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, observers

In a controller I have the following observer:

```
observesEachFooBar: function() {
    var foos = this.get('model');
    foos.forEach(function(foo) {
        foo.set('baz', foo.get('bar'));
    });
}.observes('model.@each.bar'),
```

It gets run every time  any of the `foo`s have their `bar` property modified,
and then iterates over all of the, and sets each of the `baz` properties.

Let's say that I would like to be more speicifc.
I would like to set up an observer such that it tells me which individual `foo`
has been updated,
so that I only need to update just that one.
How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

You would do this using an item controller.  This essentially means you set up the observer at the individual item's level.

```
App.FooController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'bar'
});

App.BarController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  observesBar: function(){
    this.set('baz', this.get('bar'));
  }.observes('bar')
});
```